# Trip switch goes off 50% of the time when turning off an appliance

Tags: electrical

I have my computer attached to a six plug board that has its own on/off switch. It also has a power light and an 'earth' light which both are on. 
When I click off the board using its own switch about 50% of the time it trips the switch to the whole house. 
I thought trip switches only trip when turning something on not off.

Not sure if it is dangerous but any advice would be good.

Comment: Try "turning off" the board by unplugging it, rather than flipping its switch.  If that doesn't rip the whole house breaker, then you'll know there's something wrong in the board switch...

Comment: Is the "earth" light telling you that it has a good earth or a bad earth connection? On all of the power strips/UPS's I have, the Earth light means that there is a wiring fault. Though I'm having trouble thinking of a wiring fault that would trip the breaker when you turn the power strip off.

Comment: Is it the main [breaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker) that is tripping or the [RCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device)?

Comment: Please mention your location, as the answer may be different depending on where you are.

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to answer this because there are unknowns.

- What does that earth light mean? No earth/ground/ or there is a ground.
- How's it wired inside? If they wire it between live/hot and earth/ground that is already an imbalance. Maybe the switch on the 6-way is double pole and neutral opens before the hot. That will cause an imbalance and may trip it.

Try another 6-way with no earth indicator.

Or unplug the strip not switching off the strip's switch. Just leave it on.